# Excel macro runs from usb keeps looping

Tags: vba, excel, macros, usb

I've an excel file that has a  macro which opens another sheets and scrap some cells data , it happens by browsing through a folder then looking through subfolder
this is the whole macro

```
Public strFileFullName As String
Public currentIndex As Integer
Public strFileFileName As String


'Callback for customButton onAction
Sub ScrapData(control As IRibbonControl)

 strFileFullName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
strFileFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name

'clear results sheet
Sheets("Results").Activate
Size = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Results").Columns(12))
Dim defRange As String
defRange = "A" & 2 & ":L" & CStr(Size + 1)
Worksheets("Results").Range(defRange).Clear
currentIndex = 2

'browse for file
  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then

            FolderName = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

    If (FolderName <> "") Then
    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(FolderName)
    End If
End Sub

Sub CheckFile(file As String)
      If (InStr(file, ".xlsm") > 0) And (file <> strFileFullName) Then
         Call copyCell(file)
         Exit Sub
      End If
End Sub

Sub copyCell(FileName As String)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler1

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks.Open FileName:=FileName
If (SheetExists("Home", ActiveWorkbook) And SheetExists("Front Section", ActiveWorkbook)) Then
    'start copying from Home Sheet
    Sheets("Home").Activate
    AccessorName = Cells(26, "H").Value
    LearnerName = Cells(21, "H").Value
    Framework = Cells(6, "F").Value

   'Start copying from front section sheet
    Sheets("Front Section").Activate
    StartDate = Cells(5, "G").Value
    EndDate = Cells(6, "G").Value
    Overall = Cells(7, "G").Text
    DaysLeft = Cells(8, "P").Value
    Status = Cells(9, "P").Value
    NVQ = Cells(4, "P").Text
    TC = Cells(5, "P").Text
    ErrCel = Cells(6, "P").Text
    FS = Cells(7, "P").Text

   Else
    GoTo ErrorHandler1
  End If

  'close opened sheet
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'start pasting into out sheet
    Sheets("Results").Activate
    Size = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Results").Columns(12))
    currentIndex = Size + 1
    Cells(currentIndex, 1).Value = AccessorName
    Cells(currentIndex, 2).Value = LearnerName
    Cells(currentIndex, 3).Value = Framework

    Cells(currentIndex, 4).Value = StartDate
    Cells(currentIndex, 5).Value = EndDate
    Cells(currentIndex, 6).Value = Overall
    Cells(currentIndex, 7).Value = DaysLeft
    Cells(currentIndex, 8).Value = Status
    Cells(currentIndex, 9).Value = NVQ
    Cells(currentIndex, 10).Value = TC
    Cells(currentIndex, 11).Value = ErrCel
    Cells(currentIndex, 12).Value = FS
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler1:
If ((ActiveWorkbook.FullName <> strFileFullName) Or (ActiveWorkbook.Name) <> strFileFileName) Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Exit Sub

Exit Sub

End Sub



Sub DoFolder(Folder)
    Dim SubFolder
    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        DoFolder SubFolder

    Next

    Dim file
    For Each file In Folder.Files
        CheckFile (file)
    Next
End Sub

Function SheetExists(shtName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim sht As Worksheet

     If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
     On Error Resume Next
     Set sht = wb.Sheets(shtName)
     On Error GoTo 0
     SheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing
 End Function
```

this macro works fine if that scraper file and scraped files are on desktop or if the scraper file is on usb and scraped files are on desktop

the problem raises when they all exist on usb
it loops multiple time on the same file and repeats calling `CheckFile` function
I think it's a threading problem but I can't solve it .. 
if you can help me , it'd be great

> Edit

I forgot to say that the output (the total rows) every run differs from the previous one (the output should be the same as long as the scraped files are the same)

Comment: Please provide all the code and a reproducible test case so that someone can help you debugging.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ : it's done, hope that helps. Thanks

Comment: Doubt this is a threading issue (VBA isn't multi-threaded). I suspect it has more to do with the fact that you're performing file operations during your traversal of the directory. Try commenting out the line `CheckFile (file)` and replacing it with `Debug.Print file.Path` to see if it still repeats file paths when you aren't mucking around with the files.

Comment: @Comintern : yes after commenting that function , it prints the main files only without repeating. then how that can be solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, it appears that the USB interface is interfering with the FSO's enumeration of files if the files are being accessed while it is completing the directory traversal.  One solution would be to cache the file paths in one pass, then perform operations on them in a second pass:

```
Private found As Collection 'Module scope.

Sub ScrapData(control As IRibbonControl)

    strFileFullName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    strFileFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    'clear results sheet
    Sheets("Results").Activate
    Size = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Results").Columns(12))
    Dim defRange As String
    defRange = "A" & 2 & ":L" & CStr(Size + 1)
    Worksheets("Results").Range(defRange).Clear
    currentIndex = 2

    'browse for file
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then
            FolderName = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

    If (FolderName <> "") Then
        Dim FileSystem As Object
        Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set found = New Collection
        'Data gathering pass...
        DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(FolderName)

        Dim path As Variant
        'Processing pass gathering pass...
        For Each path In found
            CheckFile path
        Next path
    End If
End Sub

Sub DoFolder(Folder)
    Dim SubFolder
    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        DoFolder SubFolder
    Next
    Dim file
    For Each file In Folder.Files
        found.Add file
    Next
End Sub
```

EDIT: The more I think about this, I'm surprised that it works on a *non-USB* drive - when you open an Excel document it creates a hidden lock file in the directory (~$filename.xlsm) that should be invalidating the FSO's directory cache.

Comment: Thanks it works as expected, and yes it was working on non-usb drive and I checked the file path string.